# Air-conditioning intermittent failure

Tags: ac, skoda

I drive a 2007 model Skoda Fabia 1.4Ltr mpl. My air conditioning trips off after driving for 5minute. Hardly stays on during traffic. Fan still rolls but cooling stops. Also noticed it tries staying on for a while but only when I increase the fan speed and am on high speed.

It cools very well at those times it stays on. Kindly assist with possible problems and solution. I want to know if its the compressor failing (which I guess not . Or something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hi Charles. Welcome to MVM&R. It appears that you have asked the same question twice. I have flagged your _other_ question to be closed as _this_ was the most complete of the two :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest your refrigerant is low and needs a recharge. It can get to a point where there is enough for the A/C to kick on, but not enough to actually cool it for very long. When the system sits idle, the refrigerant will equalize in the system between the low/high sides. When in this state, it will cool the interior of your car for a short period of time, then the cooling capacity will diminish. With it correctly recharged, you should be in good shape. I doubt there is anything mechanically wrong with the system, mainly because it *does work*, just for a short period of time.

Comment: I’ve [a similar problem](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/68429) maybe you can help ? I mean the cooling temperature lever after 1 hour on the motorway is at the level you can expect after starting the engine of a car.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 2 things. Check the switch/fuse that runs the ac. Possible fault frm there.
Or
Check the compressor. If its old, change it