# Air Conditionning cools very low, I mean nearly not at all

Tags: toyota, ac, yaris, lpg

There’s 4 airflow speed on the car switch. They aren’t affected by whether Air conditioning is enabled or not.
However, even by setting air temperature to the lowest, there’s almost no difference between the case Air conditioning is enabled or it’s disabled. It’s so much that I can’t feel the difference of temperature at air flow speed 3 and 4 (so while there’s a difference which is hard to notice opening the windows is definitely more efficient under a sunny weather without clouds).

I’m talking about this because the problem persists even after leaving the air conditioner at full speed and lowest temperature after 1 hour while driving on the motorway.
Radiator fans’ start almost always immediately when I enable air conditioning even straight after starting the engine and the cold engine is still on (so radiator fans’s is always on when air conditioning is enabled). In that case Radiator fans’ stop after pushing the air conditioner button for switching it off.
Engine ʀᴘᴍ runs a little faster (which sounds normals) and enabling air conditioning works very fast at removing mist (so while the air is almost not cooler it’s definitely dryer).
There’s no ᴏʙᴅ error codes about the air conditionner system.

As I never traveled inside a Toyota during summer I don’t know if it’s not normal or Toyota designed their cars so that drivers or passengers can’t get sick/cold by putting the temperature of their air conditioner temperature’s too low (I bought the car at the beginning of last winter so I could only ensure that heating the car works and can put the temperature inside the car to 15℃ in 3 minutes when outside temperature is 0℃ or below so heating definitely works far better than cooling).

**If it’s not normal, then where does the problem can come from ? And, how to confirm the supposed root cause of the issue ?**

## Update :

It was simply the matter of replacing the old gas.

Comment: It’s a 2007 Yaris, running long on gasoline instead of lpg doesn’t makes any differences.

Comment: If you pop the hood and check the refrigerant lines while the AC is running ... does one of them get cold? You state the fans are kicking on with the AC switch. This is a good sign. Most every vehicle I've seen will only kick the fans on if the compressor is running. If the compressor isn't running, the fans won't kick on. If one of your AC lines is cold, I'd suggest the issue is the blend door may be stuck to the hot side, or mostly to the hot side.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 i don't even know where the refrigerent is. So where to check this?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the point is fans always start even on cold engine. Whereas from what I saw elsewhere they only start because the engine produce more heat with the air conditionner enabled and temperature is above 80℃.

Comment: Usually happens when the ac refrigerant level is so low that the compressor is able to run but the evaporator is being fed with vapor instead of liquid and not so much expansion (which is what takes the heat away) is taking place inside. Do you hear a hissing noise under the footwell whenever you turn AC on? Do you see the compressor clutch rotating when you turn AC on and blower on at the same time?

Comment: @Al_ there’s no additional sound when air conditioner is enabled or disabled. Refrigerent/compressor/evaporator… I’ve no idea where those things are in the engine compartment.

Comment: The compressor is easy to find. Look at the belt area. You probably have a serpentine. Well, everything that isn't an alternator, a water pump, a power steering pump or an idler pulley is an air conditioning compressor. Google for Denso 471-1622, this should be your compressor. I just noticed that you have a clutchless compressor on your car (older Yaris had clutch) so you can't have any look at a clutch to check if it's working properly. You'll need to have the high side and low side pressures checked to see if the compressor is responding to the control unit signal whenever AC is turned on.

Comment: Evaporator is an heat exchanger located inside that box under the passenger footwell. A couple of pipes running through the firewall exchange refrigerant between its thermal expansion valve and the rest of the AC system. No hissing noise at all could either mean you have the correct charge or the compressor isn't coming into stroke and stays "short circuit" so to speak, that is, refrigerant is flowing only inside it and not through the system; either that or the pulley is defective and the compressor's shaft is not turning at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal. If you set the AC to the coldest setting, it should produce cold air. Can only guess the root cause, but it sounds like the AC system needs to be serviced. It could simply need some refrigerant added. Or it could be something major like the compressor or such being bad.

AC service is not typically a "do it yourself" maintenance item. The system is under pressure and the refrigerant should not be released into the atmosphere. My guess is that if you had the proper tools to service this, you would know how to solve it.

Comment: Really, I don't think the OP is asking how to fix it, but to figure out what may be going on. This is a simple way *not to get taken* at the garage when you take your vehicle in. Obviously it needs serviced. Is there anything else constructive for advice you might be able to give the OP?

Comment: @CharlieRB air is cooler when the air conditioner is enabled. It’s just with more air flow to cool, the difference is harder to notice.